# distinguish between design-time and run-time for an ActiveX in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, runtime, activex, design-time

I have created an ActiveX control using Visual C++ to use in my another program. i want to add an hardware-ID-related license code, to be placed beside it when design-time, to ensure just authorized persons can use it for their programs. in other word, not any one who gets my software use my ActiveX for his programs. the code should be checked just when design-time and the ActiveX should work normally without the code when run-time.
Now, how i can distinguish between design-time and run-time for an ActiveX?

Thanks...

Comment: Did you create the control using ATL, MFC or something else?

Comment: If MFC and you derived from `COleControl`, there is a method called `AmbientUserMode()` that returns FALSE if in design mode.

Comment: I am using mfc and the activex is not based any control.

Comment: If your ActiveX class doesn't derive from `COleControl` then is it an ATL control - surely you didn't develop a COM component from scratch? Can you show at least part of the `class` declaration?

Comment: Yes you are right :) base class is COleControl
`class CPCalendarCtrl : public COleControl`